# DBUnit - integrity constraint violation: foreign key no action; SYS_FK_10556

Tags: java, database, eclipse, unit-testing, dbunit

I am currently coding test with dbunit(using hsqldb). However, I have a huge Problem at initializing the db:

here`s the code:

```
/**
     * Init before a test starts
     */
    @Before
    public void initialise() {
        IDataSet dataSetRating = null;
        IDataSet dataSetMovie = null;

        log.info("enter init test");

        try {
            con = datasource.getConnection();
            icon = new DatabaseConnection(con);
            File rating = new File("./src/test/resources/startDatabaseRating.xml");         
            dataSetRating = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(rating);
            DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(icon, dataSetRating);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error(e);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
```

my create statement looks like that:

```
CREATE TABLE Rating
(
    rid INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    mid INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Movie(movieId), 
    rating INTEGER NOT NULL, 
);
```

and my startDatabaseRating.xml looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <Rating rid="0" mid="0" rating="1" />
    <Rating rid="1" mid="0" rating="2" />
    <Rating rid="2" mid="0" rating="3" />
    <Rating rid="3" mid="0" rating="4" />

    <Movie movieid="0" title="Movie1" moviePath="C" />
    <Movie movieid="1" title="Movie2" moviePath="D" />
</dataset>
```

When I run the tests I get:

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity
>   constraint violation: foreign key no action; SYS_FK_10556 table:
>   RATING

Why do I get this exception, cause there is still a dataset in the *.xml file. How to fix this problem?

**UPDATE:**

```
CREATE TABLE Movie
(
    movieId INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    moviePath VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: show us "create table" for Movie

Comment: I updated my post with the "create table" Movie...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When inserting a rating, the movie that is referenced must already exist in the `movie` table. So you are inserting the rows in the wrong order.

You need to first insert the movies, **then** the ratings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <Movie movieid="0" title="Movie1" moviePath="C" />
    <Movie movieid="1" title="Movie2" moviePath="D" />

    <Rating rid="0" mid="0" rating="1" />
    <Rating rid="1" mid="0" rating="2" />
    <Rating rid="2" mid="0" rating="3" />
    <Rating rid="3" mid="0" rating="4" />
</dataset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also I would recommand you to use regular labels for your columns, **especially for the id and the foreign key**, because it is much more easier to understand and to maintain, if another person is in charge of your code some day !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <Movie id="0" title="Movie1" moviePath="C" />
    <Movie id="1" title="Movie2" moviePath="D" />

    <Rating id="0" movie_id="0" rating="1" />
    <Rating id="1" movie_id="0" rating="2" />
    <Rating id="2" movie_id="0" rating="3" />
    <Rating id="3" movie_id="0" rating="4" />
</dataset>
```